# Declare interface that respect mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

On a typescript project, I have created the following mapped type `GlanceOsComparatorV2`

```
interface DonutData {
  label: string;
  value: number;
}

interface ProjectMetric {
  value: number;
}

enum ZoneMetricId {
  ClickRate = 'clickRate',
}
enum PageMetricId {
  ActivityRate = 'activityRate',
  BounceRate = 'bounceRate'
}

type MetricId =
  | ZoneMetricId
  | PageMetricId

type MetricLabel = 'device' | 'appVersion';

type GlanceKeyCustomV2 = `${MetricId}-${MetricLabel}-app`;

type GlanceKeyV2 = GlanceKeyCustomV2 | MetricId;

type GlanceOsComparatorV2<T> = {
  [to in GlanceKeyV2]: T | DonutData[];
}
```

Then I want to create an interface that all it's property satisfy the mapped type `GlanceOsComparatorV2<ProjectMetric>`, like this :

```
interface GlanceOsComparator {
  ['clickRate-device-app']: DonutData[];
  ['clickRate-appVersion-app']: DonutData[];
  [ZoneMetricId.ClickRate]: ProjectMetric;
};
```

My problem is how I could declare my interface `GlanceOsComparator` so that if I add a property that doesn't match `GlanceKeyV2` a typescript error is throw ?

ie: I want this to throw an error

```
interface GlanceOsComparator {
  ['test-error']: DonutData[]; // THIS SHOULD NOT BE POSSIBLE
};
```

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think there is a thing like that currently, but I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlXR5N). Does it work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, it could work yes, but I'm not very fan of creating a unused type just for checking if an error occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired behavior without creating an unused type, you could leverage TypeScript's [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) to enforce the constraints directly on the `GlanceOsComparator` interface.

That would involve defining the interface such that any keys not matching `GlanceKeyV2` will result in a type error.

From [tsplay.dev](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsQFcyrmOZAbwFgAoZZAGzgCMIqAuZAZzClAHMBucygNzhUsEZtgC29KLzIBfcuVCRYiFAAUo6AFYQEYALIR2wBMT7JBw0cglSZ8suQgTkALUwRDxhAEkAJmYUyADCVCYA1gBK+CgAvMgARAhhCFExCQA05A5OLmpwnJ5GHL4BpEEAgnrA-MBgAJ7RkMjxCYhgNXWN6VlBAELoWCBITXGJtIPDEKOZ2QpkDQAOKF4l-i1uHqsm6wA+yPmF26Uy5EsrxSYAMnQMGwl+ELVICcj7bYuLAGrQLMCYCVOC3qy2QAHEaFMANIQerBLBsdDiL4AJg2AAMACREY7+WQAWmxxxu9CoBLgn3RQPO4MhSBh9VRGwhcGhsPhiORaP2uL81JBKBZUwA8ixgkjFnAoPh0FBUQAeAAqAD4NuVKABtMDoZCgWms+mw1EAXWYireaEwODwBA1xvsQIA9I7kAAJBjLKDIGna5DOGCypDegAWKHCsOQCEwbGlSmQrICQio6AA7shJVAOkJdeJFlQIOJnAQOpgzgLkAB1OrBoWGxkopWq+L5TPAITy9XIDVQ3UgZDh+roGDIRWm5A9iAAD0gID8LH1bPryAA-CPu8bkGIntB7MqnS6fOBoPAgynq5Ho+w4KAIAEByxFEeVEHaxBReLc1KZV6pzO55Xq1fBkFVfd8JS-bU5QbDRtF0AxLgQZVVSIHIyGdZAAFUWAKFApzgXN8wfMgoxANgLCEYA-A-DNv2YUCxXA6VILVcwAHJkgiUZ8UeZ4IHxClFlY5gNSIahbiYZBWIAUUnfC8wgViMnIqxmAARgABmQWRjV6Sh2JSNJIH4z4figP5MGMwThNEmhSWYaTZIIhSlMsEQ1M07TdK7dwQCKbx-AAOlCTiYjHUTXOsDStOyfdMOGJFC3ALgQ2AeczyoKgQ00NNCEVAUAGUEA4RYwD9KBNCgch0JIsjQEsSjqIg2U6LpN8GM-JjZRYtCXT0yA2HxaAKqErsbPE+yZLk-NFOUtzkCi7TkHQqTytlKrHVkGQgA)

```js
interface DonutData {
  label: string;
  value: number;
}

interface ProjectMetric {
  value: number;
}

enum ZoneMetricId {
  ClickRate = "clickRate",
}

enum PageMetricId {
  ActivityRate = "activityRate",
  BounceRate = "bounceRate",
}

type MetricId = ZoneMetricId | PageMetricId;

type MetricLabel = "device" | "appVersion";

type GlanceKeyCustomV2 = `${MetricId}-${MetricLabel}-app`;

type GlanceKeyV2 = GlanceKeyCustomV2 | MetricId;

type GlanceOsComparatorV2<T> = {
  [to in GlanceKeyV2]: T | DonutData[];
};

// Helper type to enforce the key constraint and allow partial implementation
type WithGlanceKeyV2<T> = Partial<{
  [K in keyof T]: K extends GlanceKeyV2 ? T[K] : never;
}>;

// Interface with constrained keys
interface GlanceOsComparator extends WithGlanceKeyV2<GlanceOsComparatorV2<ProjectMetric>> {}

// Usage examples
const validComparator: GlanceOsComparator = {
  'clickRate-device-app': [{ label: 'Example', value: 10 }],
  'clickRate-appVersion-app': [{ label: 'Example', value: 10 }],
  [ZoneMetricId.ClickRate]: { value: 10 }
};

// Uncommenting this will throw a TypeScript error
// const invalidComparator: GlanceOsComparator = {
//   'test-error': [{ label: 'Example', value: 10 }] // Error
//};
```

`GlanceOsComparatorV2<T>` is a mapped type that creates a dictionary where each key is a string from `GlanceKeyV2` and the value is either type `T` or `DonutData[]`.

The `WithGlanceKeyV2<T>` type uses a conditional mapped type to iterate over the keys of `GlanceOsComparatorV2<ProjectMetric>`.

- For each key `K`, it checks if `K` is assignable to `GlanceKeyV2`. If it is, the type of the property is preserved. If not, the type is set to `never`.
- By wrapping this mapped type in `Partial`, we make each property optional, which means that `GlanceOsComparator` can implement any subset of these keys without requiring all of them.

The interface `GlanceOsComparator` extends `WithGlanceKeyV2<GlanceOsComparatorV2<ProjectMetric>>`. That means it inherits the conditional property checks from `WithGlanceKeyV2`.
As a result, any key added to an object of type `GlanceOsComparator` that does not exist in `GlanceKeyV2` would be of type `never`. TypeScript will flag any property with type `never` as an error, unless the property is explicitly omitted.

Usage examples:

- The `validComparator` object demonstrates a valid usage of the `GlanceOsComparator` interface. It only uses keys that are part of `GlanceKeyV2`.
- The commented-out `invalidComparator` object illustrates what would happen if you try to add a property that is not in `GlanceKeyV2`. If you uncomment this part, TypeScript will throw an error because `'test-error'` is not a valid key according to `GlanceKeyV2`.

In the last case, the error would be:

```
Type '{ 'test-error': { label: string; value: number; }[]; }' is not assignable 
to type 'Partial<{ clickRate: ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; activityRate: ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; bounceRate: ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; 5 more ...; "bounceRate-appVersion-app": ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; }>'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''test-error'' does not exist 
in type 'Partial<{ clickRate: ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; activityRate: ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; bounceRate: ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; 5 more ...; "bounceRate-appVersion-app": ProjectMetric | DonutData[]; }>'.
```

That does indicate that the TypeScript compiler has correctly identified that the key `'test-error'` is not a valid property of the `GlanceOsComparator` type. That is because `'test-error'` is not a key in `GlanceKeyV2`, and therefore it cannot be used in the `GlanceOsComparator` interface as per the constraints defined in the `WithGlanceKeyV2<T>` type.

The error confirms that the code is functioning as intended: it allows only properties that match keys in `GlanceKeyV2` within the `GlanceOsComparator` interface, and any attempt to use keys outside this set will result in a TypeScript compilation error. That behavior makes sure the interface respects the constraints of the mapped type `GlanceOsComparatorV2<ProjectMetric>`.

Comment: It sounds good like you do, but I have some errors for GlanceOsComparator interface : see https://tsplay.dev/mLrpAw

Comment: @NathanBruet I have edited (and tested in tsplay.dev) the answer to address your comment.